# Coloring table row ruins \pm symbol

Tags: tables, amsmath, colortbl

If I use `\rowcolor` the `\pm` symbol that I have in the row gets cropped, it seems.

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}

\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{EEEEEE}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{lcD{.}{.}{3}p{0cm}D{.}{.}{3}}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Model} & \textbf{MAPE} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Time (s)}}\\
        \midrule
        \rowcolor{lightgray} \texttt{snaive} & 29.28\% & 0.003 & $\pm$ &
            0.001\\
        \texttt{ARIMA} & 34.02\% & 22.480 & $\pm$ & 13.210\\
        \rowcolor{lightgray} \texttt{GAM} & 15.32\% & 18.481 & $\pm$ &
            0.854\\
        \rowcolor{lightgray} \texttt{GAMM[p = 1]} & 11.06\% & 447.861 &
            $\pm$ & 191.182\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This is the resulting output:
[image: table]

The problem is really visible, but here it is the zoomed-in version:

[image: symbols]

They appear cropped to the right. I don't know what would cause this and how I could fix it.

Comment: `p{0cm}` is too small change to `p{5mm}` for example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give some value in para mode definition instead of zero, i.e.,     `\begin{tabular}{lcD{.}{.}{3}p{**1cm**}D{.}{.}{3}}`

Comment: You're right, it works now. I wonder why it a width of 0 is enough when `\rowcolor` is not used.

Comment: @rubik Because, when you are not coloring the row, it is not necessarily a problem if the glyph hangs over into the next column.  But if you are coloring the row, then the overhang gets overwritten by the next column's color box.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Great, nice explanation...

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks Steven, the explanation was very clear!