# Problem with rowcolors and @{} in tabular environment

Tags: colortbl

I would like to insert the \pm symbol between a pair of numbers on each line of a table.

[image: simple table without shaded rows]

I would like to alternately color the rows. I tried to use the rowcolors package but this overwrites the symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.92}
\begin{document}
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\begin{tabular}{r@{$\pm$}r}
 1 & 0.5 \\
  1 & 0.5 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

But this produces:

[image: Table with grey rows but overwritten symbol]

This [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393315/coloring-table-row-ruins-pm-symbol) is related but I cannot see how to use this while maintaining the spacing, without introducing white patches in the row color.

Answer (score 5):

I can't find the error, but I propose another solution:

- `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}`
- `>{$\pm$}` in front of the content of the second column

**The code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.92}
\begin{document}
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{r >{$\pm$}r}
1 & 0.5 \\
12345 & 0.5 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: Another solution with the package `tabularray`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.92}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {Q[r,mode=math] Q[l,mode=math]},
    vline{2} = {text=\clap{$\pm$}},
    %
    row{even} = {lightgray},
    }
    1 & 0.5 \\
    12345 & 0.5 \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.92}
\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{r@{$\pm$}r}
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\Body
  1 & 0.5 \\
  1 & 0.5 \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 3):

With `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.92}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={lr},
    column{1}={rightsep=0.7pt},
    column{2}={leftsep=0pt},
    cell{1-Z}{1}={appto={\pm}},
    cell{even}{1-Z}={lightgray},
    }
1 & 0.5 \\
1 & 0.5 \\
\end{tblr}
\]
In case there is a header:
\[
\begin{tblr}{
    hspan=minimal,
    colspec={Q[1.6em,r]Q[1.6em,l]},
    column{1}={rightsep=0.7pt},
    column{2}={leftsep=0pt},
    cell{1}{1}={c=2}{c, mode=text},
    cell{2-Z}{1}={appto={\pm}},
    cell{odd[2-Z]}{1-Z}={lightgray},
    }
Header&\\
1 & 0.5 \\
1 & 0.5 \\
\end{tblr}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]